# Replace all urls in string not matching pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using this code to replace urls in a string

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text)
```

How do I do the same thing, but keeping urls that match a certain pattern (ie start with a domain I want to keep)?

**Update**

Turns out that the urls I want to keep include relative urls, so I now want to eliminate all  urls that don't match the given url pattern and are not relative links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
preg_replace('#<a(?![^>]+?href="?http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar"?).*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text);
```

**Edit:** If you want to match only relative domains, the logic is the same. Just take out the protocol and domain name:

```
preg_replace('#<a(?![^>]+?href="?/?path/to/foo/bar"?).*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text);
```

The `?` after `"` and `/` means that those characters are optional. So, the second example will work for either `path/to/foo/bar` or `/path/to/foo/bar`.

Comment: How do I get this to keep relative urls in addition to the ones matching the keep domain?

Comment: Just tweak it; see my edit. Please accept the answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: Was also wondering how to replace urls that appear in the text even if they are not hyperlinks.  So a free form url would be stripped out as well.  Keeping urls that match the keepthisdomain of course.  I will be applying the hyperlink strip regex before the free form strip regex

Comment: @lordmj The logic here is the same. Just use the first version, without the portions relevant to anchor tags, like so: `preg_replace('#(?!http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar)http://[^<>\s]*#i', '\1', $text);` Note: this may require some tweaking, because it would apply to *everything*, not just plain text. So, it might nuke some `img` tags, for example. You would need to modify the "good" URL pattern to preserve anything you want to keep.

Comment: Revisitng this again.  Now I want to remove the same hyperlinks as before.  But if it has the attribute rel="shadowbox[a]" I want to keep the hyperlink.

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, please post it as a separate question -- that way, there's only one question per page. :)

Comment: Ok follow up question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209474/replace-all-urls-in-string-not-matching-url-pattern-in-php