# Replace all urls in string not matching url pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the following code to filter out urls from a block of HTML text in PHP.

```
preg_replace('#<a(?![^>]+?href="?http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar"?).*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text);
```

It's intended to replace all url's that do not match the specified url pattern.  However I do want to include all  tags that have the attribute rel="shadowbox[a]"  set.

How can I modify this preg_replace to do that?

Comment: To clarify, which is a match: (1) `a` tags with the specified URL pattern *and* the `rel="shadowbox[a]"` attribute, or (2) `a` tags with the specified URL pattern *or* the `rel="shadowbox[a]"` attribute?

Comment: P.S. You are better off not using regex at all and using a parser instead, for [the reasons set forth in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919).

Comment: It's a tag with the rel="shadowbox[a]" attribute.  I want to keep those urls (along with all hyperlinks that link to http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar)

Answer (score 0):

You are better off not using regex at all and using a parser instead, for [the reasons set forth in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919).

That said, you can do it with regex, but it's tricky:

```
preg_replace('#<a(?![^>]+?\bhref="?http://keepthisdomain\.com/foo/bar"?|[^>]+\brel="shadowbox\[a\]").*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text);
```

Details on the regex:

```
<a(?![^>]+?\bhref="?http://keepthisdomain\.com/foo/bar"?|[^>]+\brel="shadowbox\[a\]").*?>(.*?)</a>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Out of the following four tags, only the third would be replaced:

```
<a href="http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar">foo</a> // left alone
<a href="http://keepthisdomain.com/foo/bar" rel="shadowbox[a]">foo</a> // left alone
<a href="http://rejectthis.com/foo/bar">foo</a> // REPLACED
<a href="http://rejectthis.com/foo/bar" rel="shadowbox[a]">foo</a> // left alone
```

*Edited with a minor tweak to make it match a literal `.` in `.com`, using `\.`*